# Event listener for multiple elements - jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

In the ASP MVC page I'm currently working on, the values of three input fields determine the value of a fourth. Zip code, state code, and something else called a Chanel Code will determine what the value of the fourth field, called the Territory Code, will be.

I just started learning jQuery a couple weeks ago, so I would first think you could put a `.change` event that checks for values in the other two fields and, if they exists, call a separate method that compares the three and determines the Territory code. However, I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to approach this since it seems like writing a lot of the same code in different places.

Comment: I don't see why you would need more than 1 function to do the calculations, or more than 1 event handler to fire the helper function.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can bind a callback to multiple elements by specifying multiple selectors:

```
$(".field1, .field2, .field3").click(function() {
    return field1 +
           field2 + 
           field3;
});
```

If you need to perform specific actions depending on which element was clicked, another option would be to create a function which performs the actual computation and then invoke that from each callback.

```
var calculate = function() {
    return field1 +
           field2 + 
           field3;
};
```

And then invoke this function when on each click:

```
$(".field1").click(function() {
    // Perform field1-specific logic
    calculate();
});

$(".field2").click(function() {
    // Perform field2-specific logic
    calculate();
});

// etc..
```

This means that you do not repeat yourself.

Comment: I don't think you would want run these onClick. The functions would run before there were any values in the input fields. You could do something like this, but use `blur` instead of `click`. That way when the user moves to the next field, `calculate()` is called.

Comment: @Luke click was just an example to demonstrate the principle. This will work equally well for blur/change/whatever.

Comment: That's basically what I was thinking. Having one function called by each event. Since the logic for each event will be different, this is probably about as much as it can be simplified. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This works for me

```
jQuery(document).on('scroll', ['body', window, 'html', document], 
    function(){
        console.log('multiple')
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another possibility, just in cased this may help someone. This version should work on dynamically created fields.

```
$("#form").on('change', '#Field1, #Field2, #Field3', function (e) {        
    e.preventDefault();  

    console.log('something changed');           

});
```