# How to let onclick(); listens to more than one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-selectors

I am trying to let Jq listen to three buttons at the same onclick method 
then trigger a function and call the clicked button by $(this);

here is a sample :

```
$("body").on('click', 'a.home:visible', 'a.mobile:visible', 'a.phone:visible', function () {
        var attr = $(this).attr('attr');


        $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').prev().prev().text(attr);
    });
```

Comment: For the time being i will let all the buttons share the same class and then trigger the event since in my case sharing same class is possible ;

Comment: waiting geeks to tell how to let onclick event listen to multi item selector :)

Comment: your selector should be a string separated by commas, not separate arguments

Comment: @guradio no its not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event listener for multiple elements - jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286936/event-listener-for-multiple-elements-jquery)

Comment: @billyonecan you deserve a gold medal

Comment: @billyonecan they are not `arguments`, they are `parameters`. ;)

Comment: @eisbehr you pass arguments to parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did it basically correct. Your approach is fine. But you have to combine it in one string, not as single parameters. And you don't need `:visible`, because you can't `click` on invisible elements. ;)

```
$("body").on('click', 'a.home, a.mobile, a.phone', function() {
    var attr = $(this).attr('attr');
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').prev().prev().text(attr);
});
```

If the elements are static you should even use a normal event listener instead of a delegation.

```
$('a.home, a.mobile, a.phone').click(function() {
    var attr = $(this).attr('attr');
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').prev().prev().text(attr);
});
```

Comment: thank you for lighting this up to me , can you please describe more about static elements I mean how to judge that this element is static in order to use the suggested aparoche ?

Comment: Static means, the element is only created once on page creation. A dynamic element could be added with AJAX or created by any other script. Then use it like you did in your example. If they are static, the second one would be the better choice. @SuhaybKharabsheh

Comment: @eisbeht so it's dynamic since i am cloning that phone field more and more as you click and that buttons user click are created after DOM is ready ,thanks

Comment: Yes, they are dynamically then. So your approach was right, execpt my changes. :) @SuhaybKharabsheh

Answer (score 1):

Put them in one quotes

```
$("body").on('click', 'a.home:visible,a.mobile:visible,a.phone:visible', function() {
  alert('Clicked')

});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/f90wzoqv/)