# jQuery Selector from jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How can I listen to the `onChange` Event of multiple jQuery objects?

```
var el1= jQuery('input[type="checkbox"][name="x"]');
var el2= jQuery('input[type="checkbox"][name="y"]');
jQuery(el1, el2).change(function (e) {
    //....
});
```

Of course I could just put the 2 element selectors as a string into the
`.change` function, but this is a simplified example. I would like to work with the jQuery objects, not with string selectors.

This looked like a simple "let me google for you" question to me, but I have not been able to find a solution for the past hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `add()` or `merge()` method:

Add:

```
el1.add(el2).change(function (e) {
    //....
});
```

Merge:

```
$.merge(el1, el2).change(function (e) {
    //....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var el1 = jQuery('input[type="checkbox"][name="x"]');
var el2 = jQuery('input[type="checkbox"][name="y"]');


$(document).on('change', [el1, el2], function() {
  console.log('multiple')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="el1">Element 1</label>
<input id="el1" type="checkbox" name="x" value="test1" />
<label for="el2">Element 2</label>
<input id="el2" type="checkbox" name="y" value="test2" />
```

Also it is the first result of google and the main link is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286936/event-listener-for-multiple-elements-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.add()`](http://devdocs.io/jquery/add):

```
el1.add(el2).on('change', function () { /* body */ });
```